# Choosing a parsing technology for a large project

Tags: java, parsing, antlr, parser-combinators

I have to deal with lots of different file formats.  At least 50, maybe more than 100.

I've played around with Antlr in the past.  However, I'm not sure that Antlr would be suitable for this project for a couple of reasons:

- it's difficult to combine and reuse grammars and/or pieces of grammars
- Antlr does code generation -- making a change to an existing parser requires going back to Antlr, making the change, regenerating the code, integrating the code back into the codebase, and running the unit-tests
- doing tree-building/-processing requires dealing with another language inside Antlr -- a potential problem for future developers

Basically, I like Antlr, but I think that it may be better suited for creating one or two parsers for complex languages, rather than 100 parsers for somewhat simpler languages/formats.

An alternative to Antlr-like parser generators is **parser combinators**.  The advantages are the parsers are directly integrated into code, making reuse, testing, and further abstraction very easy.  Also, future developers wouldn't have to learn how to use a new tool.  The downside of parser combinators is that I don't know of any heavy-duty libraries for using them in Java.

**So the questions are:**

1. Is Antlr suitable/intended for such a massive parsing project?
2. What are other options for large-scale parsing in Java?

---

Note:  some of the file formats are CSV or tab-delimited, some are somewhat more complex, some are as complex as Java.  Semantics-wise, they can also be quite complicated (although not all are).

Comment: For a wothwhile answer an important piece of information is missing: What is the complexity  of those formats both in regard to syntax and also in regard to semantic? If the complexity is like that of the Java language itself then other stuff is required. If on the other hand all formats are on the level of CSV, then a much lighter approach can be used.

Comment: `#1`: _"it's difficult to combine and reuse grammars and/or pieces of grammars"_, I disagree: you can share/import grammars into other grammars in ANTLR. `#2`: that is correct. `#3`: I don't know what you mean by that. Furthermore, I agree with A.H. that important info is still missing.

Comment: @A.H. -- thanks for the suggestion, I've updated.

Comment: @BartKiers -- I was referring to building a tree/walking the tree to convert it to, say, a domain model -- http://www.antlr.org/wiki/display/ANTLR3/4.+Tree+Parsing.  Apologies if my phraseology was poor. :)

Comment: @Matt, ah, I see. No problem. Then yes, I concur with `#3`.

Answer (score 0):

I personally have used [Apache Tika](http://tika.apache.org/0.9/formats.html) in the past which was more than suitable for my needs and covers a wide variety of formats. I have never used Antlr so can't really comment on it.

Comment: That seems to just be a collection of parsers.  ??

Comment: It is a toolkit which allows automatic file type detection, and parsing and extraction of over 70 mime types.

Answer (score 0):

[There is a parsing technique](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Packrat_parser#Implementing_parsers_from_parsing_expression_grammars) which is perfectly suitable for combining, reusing, inheriting and extending parser components (even extending a running parser in runtime).

I would never count code generation tool and a nice declarative DSL as a drawback, but probably I'm too far from the Java subculture. If these concerns are somehow valid, still, it is not a problem - you can implement Packrat using combinators. It can be a bit clumsy in Java (due to the lack of proper closures and lambdas), but still much more readable than a typical ad hoc recursive descent parser.

Comment: Implementing a parser generator is outside the scope of this project.  Using grammars is fantastic -- in fact, it's exactly what I want to do, but I need a tool to help me with it.

Comment: @Matt Fenwick, if you choose the combinators-based (or even an ad hoc) way you won't need a generator. And of course there are tools available, e.g.: http://cs.nyu.edu/rgrimm/xtc/

Comment: That looks interesting; I need to know if it's suitable for a large-scale Java project for the reasons mentioned -- do you have any experience using this tool for such a project?

Comment: @Matt Fenwick, I've only evaluated Rats! (that's the only component you'll need), and ended up implementing my own embedded Packrat anyway (and moved to .NET, so Java tools would not work for me). But it should be suitable for your requirements, it is scalable by design.